# What are some of the interesting ways that you have implemented IRouteHandler in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am curious to see how others implemented IRouteHandler. MVCRouteHandler seems limited in abilities and wondering if anybody extended in interesting ways.

Comment: MVCRouteHandler is far from limited and gets you pretty close to the bare metal of a httprequest.  Why made you think MVCRouteHandler has limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: [Country Prohibitor Route Handler](http://nayyeri.net/iroutehandler-in-asp-net-mvc)